# Странное поведения метода split со строкой, возвращаемой функцией ctime

Tags: python, время, split

Доброго времени суток! Сейчас заметил довольно странную штуку: при одинаковой строке метод split ведет себя по-разному там, где этого не должно быть. По умолчанию разделитель метода split равен пробелу, поэтому, если передать в качестве аргумента пробел, разницы быть не должно. Однако, происходит следующее: `time.ctime(0).split()  # ['Thu', 'Jan', '1', '03:00:00', '1970']
time.ctime(0).split(' ')  # ['Thu', 'Jan', '', '1', '03:00:00', '1970']`
 В чем может быть причина такого поведения? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не указывать `sep`, то по умолчанию [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) будет использовать любое количество идущих подряд пробелов/табуляций в качестве разделителя.

Пример:

```
In [164]: '1 2  3\t\t4'.split()
Out[164]: ['1', '2', '3', '4']

In [165]: '1 2  3\t\t4'.split(' ')
Out[165]: ['1', '2', '', '3\t\t4']

In [166]: '1 2  3\t\t4'.split('  ')
Out[166]: ['1 2', '3\t\t4']

In [167]: '1 2  3\t\t4'.split('\t')
Out[167]: ['1 2  3', '', '4']

In [168]: '1 2  3\t\t4'.split('\t\t')
Out[168]: ['1 2  3', '4']
```